# TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

Buen dia a todos estoy aprendiendo a como usar Redux en React mediante un curso pero en el desarrollo de un ejemplo simple me he quedado atascado por un error que no entiendo de donde sale.

Esto pasa al dar click en mi boton y es ahi donde se me llena la pantalla con ese error,la idea es obtener una lista de pokemones de una Api y guardarlos en una constante como pueden ver.

Este es el componente donde declaro los **Reduces,Acciones y Constantes** usando la estructura de Ducks llamado pokeDuck.js

```
import axios from "axios";


//constantes
//Declaramos nuestro estado y nuestras acciones todo esto en constantes


const dataInicial = [{array:[]}];
const OBTENER_POKEMONES = "OBTENER_POKEMONES";





//............................................................................................................




//reduce
//Revulve la accion especificada sto es solo una function a exportar
export default function pokeReduce(state = dataInicial,action){

        switch(action.type) {
            case OBTENER_POKEMONES:
            return {...state, array:[action.payload]}
          
        
            default:
                return state;
               
        }

}



//............................................................................................................



//acciones
//Mostrar,modificar,borrar esas son las acciones en si que tambien son funciones o contsante de tipo funcion

export function ObtenerPokemones(){

    //dispatch: Activamos al reduce
    //getState: Obtenemos la data inicial la constante de arriba
    return async function (dispatch,getState){

        try {

     
            const res = await axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=20");

            dispatch({

                type:OBTENER_POKEMONES,
                payload: res.data.results
            })

            
        } catch (error) {
            
            console.log("Hubo un problema: "+error)
        }


    }


}
```

Este es el store.js

Lo único que hago es exportar mis **reduces** y retornarlos

```
import {createStore,combineReducers,applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import pokeReduce from "./pokeDuck";


//COMBINAMOS EL REDUCES CON EL METODO combineReciders todas nuestras reduce las combinamos haca con un nombre relacionado
const rootReduce = combineReducers({

    pokemones: pokeReduce

});




export default function generarStore(){


 const store = createStore(rootReduce,applyMiddleware(thunk));
 return store;
 

}
```

Haca mi componente de **React** que solo es un simple boton que llama a la accion del pokeDuck.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from "react-redux"
import ObtenerPokemones from "../redux/pokeDuck"
//UseDispatch: nos va a servir para consumir nuestra accion del patico
//useSelector: nos va a servir para leer el estado o array

const Pokemones = () =>{

    const dispacth = useDispatch();

    return(

        <Fragment>
        <h2>Pokemones</h2>

        <button onClick={()=>{dispacth(ObtenerPokemones())}}>Obtener Pokemones</button>
        </Fragment>
    )


}

export default Pokemones;
```

Y por ultimo lo importo a mi aplicación que muestra todo que es la App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Pokemones from './components/pokemones';

import {Provider} from "react-redux"
import generarStore from "./redux/store";

function App() {

 const store = generarStore();

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>

    <Pokemones/>

    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

El error indica que algo es `undefined` antes `type`. Creo que es `action.type` en tu `pokeReduce`. Cuando usas `dispacth()` normalmente agregar un `type` y `payload` como lo hiciste aquí:

```
 dispatch({
     type:OBTENER_POKEMONES,
     payload: res.data.results
 })
```

Pero en tu componente `Pokemones` escribes: `dispacth(ObtenerPokemones())`. Creo que si solo escribes `onClick={()=> ObtenerPokemones()}}` resolveras tu problema.

Comment: No amigo sigue igual, con el mismo problema no se enserio que pasa

Comment: Okey, ¿dónde ocurre el error (type of unfefined)?

Comment: Justo en el Case me indica, dónde está la action.type

Comment: Intenté reproducir tu problema con mi respuesta y a mi me funciona. Aquí tienes el [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-microservice-2ysz9?file=/src/components/Pokemones.jsx)

Comment: Amigo ya me di de cuenta cual era el problema era una estupidez al importar PokeDuck.js no lo había importado con corchetes jejeje y tu codigo si me funciono solo que prefiero utilizar la metodología Duck. Igualmente gracias

Comment: Amiga* ;) Me alegra que lo hayas resuelto